# From a set of values, how do I find the values not stored in a table's column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which will potentially store hundreds of thousands of integers:

```
desc id_key_table;

+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id_key         | int(16)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

From a program, I have a large set of integers.  I'd like to see which of these integers are NOT in the above id_key column.

So far I've come up with the following approaches:

1) Iterate through each integer and perform a:

```
select count(*) count from id_key_table where id_key = :id_key
```

When count is 0 the id_key is missing from the table.

This seems like a horrible, horrible way to do it.

---

2) Create a temporary table, insert each of the values into the temporary table, and perform a JOIN on the two tables.

```
create temporary table id_key_table_temp (id_key int(16) primary key );

insert into id_key_table_temp values (1),(2),(3),...,(500),(501);

select temp.id_key
from id_key_table_temp temp left join id_key_table as main 
         on temp.id_key = main.id_key 
where main.killID is null;

drop table id_key_table_temp;
```

This seems like the best approach, however, I'm sure there is a far better approach I haven't thought of yet. I'd prefer to not have to create a temporary table and use one query to determine which integers are missing.

Is there a proper query for this type of search?

(MySQL)

Comment: The second option is best. (checking for speed the 3 possible ways to write the query, the `LEFT JOIN - IS NULL` you wrote, the `NOT IN` version and the `NOT EXISTS` way. Usually the 1st or the 3rd is faster in MySQL).

Comment: I guess that the id_keys you want to check are NOT sequential and that (1-501) was just an example.

Comment: ypercube, correct, the keys are not sequential.  In fact there may be very large gaps: e.g. 100000 - 150000 is populated with random numbers missing, then 230000 - 400000 is populated with random numbers missing, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your code in the second example given in the question, I created two stored procedures (SP): 1 SP to load a sample table of prime numbers as keys, the other SP to find the missing integers.

Here is the first SP:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`CreateSampleTable` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`CreateSampleTable` (maxinttoload INT)
BEGIN

  DECLARE X,OKTOUSE,MAXLOOP INT;

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.id_key_table;
  CREATE TABLE test.id_key_table (id_key INT(16)) ENGINE=MyISAM;

  SET X=2;
  WHILE X <= maxinttoload DO
    INSERT INTO test.id_key_table VALUES (X);
    SET X = X + 1;
  END WHILE;
  ALTER TABLE test.id_key_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_key);

  SET MAXLOOP = FLOOR(SQRT(maxinttoload));
  SET X = 2;
  WHILE X <= MAXLOOP DO
    DELETE FROM test.id_key_table WHERE MOD(id_key,X) = 0 AND id_key > X;
    SELECT MIN(id_key) INTO OKTOUSE FROM test.id_key_table WHERE id_key > X;
    SET X = OKTOUSE;
  END WHILE;
  OPTIMIZE TABLE test.id_key_table;

  SELECT * FROM test.id_key_table;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the second SP:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`GetMissingIntegers` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`GetMissingIntegers` (maxinttoload INT)
BEGIN

  DECLARE X INT;

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.id_key_table_temp;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test.id_key_table_temp (id_key INT(16)) ENGINE=MyISAM;

  SET X=1;
  WHILE X <= maxinttoload DO
    INSERT INTO test.id_key_table_temp VALUES (X);
    SET X = X + 1;
  END WHILE;
  ALTER TABLE test.id_key_table_temp ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_key);

  SELECT temp.id_key FROM test.id_key_table_temp temp
  LEFT JOIN test.id_key_table main USING (id_key)
  WHERE main.id_key IS NULL;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the Sample Run of First SP using the number 25 to create prime numbers:

```
mysql> CALL test.CreateSampleTable(25);
+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Table             | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| test.id_key_table | optimize | status   | OK       |
+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)

+--------+
| id_key |
+--------+
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      5 |
|      7 |
|     11 |
|     13 |
|     17 |
|     19 |
|     23 |
+--------+
9 rows in set (0.17 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the run of the second SP using 25 as the full list to compare:

```
mysql> CALL test.GetMissingIntegers(25);
+--------+
| id_key |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      4 |
|      6 |
|      8 |
|      9 |
|     10 |
|     12 |
|     14 |
|     15 |
|     16 |
|     18 |
|     20 |
|     21 |
|     22 |
|     24 |
|     25 |
+--------+
16 rows in set (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql>
```

While this solution is OK for small samples, big lists become a major headache. You may want to keep the temp table (don't use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE over and over, use CREATE TABLE just once) permamnently loaded with the numbers 1 .. MAX(id_key) and populate that permanent temp table via a trigger on id_key_table.

Just a question because I am curious: Are you doing this to see if auto_increment keys from a table can be reused ???

Comment: "Are you doing this to see if auto_increment keys from a table can be reused ???"  No way, that's crazy talk.  I'm receiving sets of data which is kind enough to provide unique identifiers and am merely trying not to reprocess already processed data.  The data will tend to repeat itself from different sources (and yet still provide the same consistent unique identifier).

Comment: @Clinton I have seen other developers actually perform this crazy talk, so I hear you.

Comment: I'll stick with my second solution and having the temp table as a permanent table.  Thank you for the feedback!